# getSelectedColumn with JTable doesn't work with changing model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree

i have a JTree, and when u click leafs, it changes the JTable model and displays a new table (much like an email system). the problem arises when i try to select the columns of the new Table model, it always gives -1, no matter what. NOTE that this works perfectly for the 1st JTable model, but after the changed table,

```
System.out.println(table.getSelectedColumn());
```

always returns -1.

EDIT: well, i dont know which code snippet to post here to be honest.

```
    //constructor
    public TreeSection() {
    super();

    //TREE
    top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("EMAIL");
    createNodes(top);
    //Create a tree that allows one selection at a time.
    tree = new JTree(top);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    //Listen for when the selection changes.
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);

    //TABLE
    tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this);


    //SCROLL PANE
    treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);
    tableView = new JScrollPane(table);

    //SPLIT PANE
    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    splitPane.setTopComponent(treeView);
    splitPane.setBottomComponent(tableView);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(400);
    splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 700));

    //Add the split pane to this panel.
    panel.add(splitPane,BorderLayout.WEST);
}

/** Required by TreeSelectionListener interface. */
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    if (node == null) return;

    Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();

    if (node.isLeaf()) {
        MailObject mObj = (MailObject)nodeInfo;
        table.removeAll();
        tableModel.setTableData(mObj.tableD);//changes tree model
        table = new JTable(tableModel);

        panel.repaint();
    }
}

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
    // Get the data model for this table
    //table.changeSelection(table.getSelectedColumn(), table.getSelectedRow(), false, false);
    TableModel model = (TableModel)table.getModel();
    System.out.println(table.getSelectedColumn());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSelectedColumn returns -1 when there is no column selected.
If you are sure that a column is being selected then perhaps when you are creating the new table you are calling getSelectedColumn on the old table?

Edit after snippet posted:
You're creating a new JTable which not only doesn't have the settings (such as FillsViewPortHeight but also doesn't have the selection model. Try replacing

```
table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

in valueChanged with

```
table.setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: im calling getSelectedColumn on a JTable variable which is continually updated with the changed model when the JTree changes it. i personally feel its a listener problem. even as ive juggled around with the listener, theres been no improvement.

Comment: thanks a million! you solved my problem! nearly wasted 3 hrs on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the backing model, it resets the selection information. Remember, a new model might even have a different number of columns, etc.

What you could do is save the selection information before you change the model, and then re-select the correct column once the new model is set.

Comment: okay, but even if i dont select anything at all until AFTER the table changes, this still happens. so in this case, there was no initial selection at all, but still gives the same problem.

Comment: So are you saying that you update the model, then select a column, and then you still get -1 as the selected column? Perhaps you could post a bit of code to make the situation more clear, or list out the actual actions that are happening?